# Excel for Mac 2016: No ribbon or toolbar on opening a file

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

[image: screenshot]

When I open a .xlsx file in Excel for Mac 2016, I *sometimes* don't see a toolbar or ribbon of any kind. It's not that the ribbon is hidden, and clicking "Home" will unhide it, because "Home" and all other navigation buttons across the top are not shown. I can still do normal work within the workbook, but if I need to edit a pivot table for example, I cannot navigate to the Pivot Table Pane button.

I haven't found any rhyme or reason for why this error continues. It looks to happen on primarily large files (200MB+). My current workaround when it happens is to close and re-open until the ribbon shows up. The fix is inconsistent and wastes time.

I have tried:

- Going full screen
- Staying out of full screen
- Opening on a different Monitor
- View > Show Ribbon (It's already checked, and click it keeps it checked)
- Tried looking at Excel > Preferences (It does not open)

I totally agree this might not be the best space for this question, so please let me know where else I can ask this question. But any input is better than pointing me in a different direction.